# Delete rows from multiple joined tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, foreign-keys, sql-delete

I have a problem with removing rows from multiple joined tables in SQL Server.

This is my script:

```
DELETE d, di, dis 
FROM Data d  
JOIN DataItem di ON di.DataId = d.DataId  
JOIN DataItemSend dis ON dis.DataItemId = di.DataItemId
WHERE d.CardId = 1555
```

But this syntax is not correct and commas on first line are underlined. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You cannot delete individual columns from a table - you delete entire rows - that's why it has to be `DELETE * FROM ...`

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server does not support deleting from multiple tables at once - unlike MySQL for example.

The way your query is built, however, makes it looks like you could just set up proper foreign keys between the tables, with the `on delete cascade` option, like so:

```
alter table DataItem 
    add constraint fk_DataItem_Data
    foreign key (DataId) references Data(DataId)
    on delete cascade
;

alter table DataItemSend 
    add constraint fk_DataItemSend_DataItem
    foreign key (DataItemId) references DataItem(DataItemId)
    on delete cascade
;
```

With this set up in place, you can just delete from the top-parent table:

```
delete from Data where CardId = 1555
```

... And rest assured that all related records in the children table will be deleted.

Comment: <personal preference>As one who has done Stupid Things℠ over the years, I shy away from `delete cascade` and instead write a stored procedure to implement the appropriate functionality. It also provides a place to do other validation and, if you choose to protect the underlying tables appropriately, prevents (most) users from directly deleting data.</personal preference>